# How does Iron Python play (mean or nice) with a C# class?

Tags: c#, integration, ironpython

I am interested in writing a few routines within my C# program in IronPython. I'm concerned about the integration. I have a simple class:

```
  public class candleStim
  {
    public virtual int       Id            { get; set; }
    public virtual int       candleNumber  { get; set; } 
    public virtual DateTime  date          { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal   open          { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal   high          { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal   low           { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal   close         { get; set; }
    public virtual List<EMA> EMAs          { get; set; } 
    public virtual List<SMA> SMAs          { get; set; }
    public virtual string    simulationID  { get; set; }
   }
```

Will a method written in IronPython understand this class? What about a simple string object, are they the same in C# and IronPython? If not, how would I go about converting? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean on 'the same or not'? IronPython is build over .NET (and with using its classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily check **how nice all that working** by your own.

I am not sure what tools are you using, but if you [setup IronPython](https://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/90087) and [IronPython Tools for VisualStudion](http://ironpython.net/tools/), you can experiment much.

The sample below is just some autogenerated IronPython Winforms project code with a reference to your class, which is built as **standard ClassLibrary C# project**. (You have to copy the assembly built to the IronPython project directory though).

*The only thing I am not sure about is EMA/SMA -- if you expecting those to be some 'standard' Python classes imported from some libraries or just some custom stuff of yours.*

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Drawing')
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')

### importing our assembly
clr.AddReference('ClassLibrary1ForPython')

from System.Drawing import *
from System.Windows.Forms import *

from ClassLibrary1ForPython import *

class MyForm(Form):
    def __init__(self):
        # Create child controls and initialize form
        pass

### your class instantiating
classInstance = candleStim()


Application.EnableVisualStyles()
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)

form = MyForm()
### setting the window title from the value of a property of your class (standard string)
form.Text = classInstance.simulationID

Application.Run(form)
```

Comment: Oops I should have included more info on the EMA and SMA classes! They are indeed my custom classes, they even have some logic on the put/get  class variables. I was wondering how that will integrate. Thanks for the links I will experiment

Comment: If those are your own custom classes, then there must be no problems with them.